# How to move a circle from a canvas with the mouse (when it's hold)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this problem, and I don't know how to deal with it. 
I struggled almost 2 hours to fix it. I tried various methods, but with no luck. If it's a nobbish question please forgive me and explain me in depth every step you do.

I have created a canvas, and I drew a circle in it. Now, I want to move the circle with the mouse, but while the mouse **is hold**. Is there any way to do it, or I'm just wasting time?
Here is the code:

```
<canvas draggable="true" id="canv" name="canv" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onclick="">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas> <!-- < -- the canvas -->

<script>

var canv = document.getElementById("canv");
var context = canv.getContext("2d");

var width = canv.offsetWidth-1;
var height = canv.offsetHeight-1;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(width/2, height/2, 75, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();

</script>
```

Some methods I have tried. These one are left in remarks /**/. Other ones I deleted them.

**1.**

```
<canvas draggable="true" id="canv" name="canv" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onclick="circle_move()"></canvas>

function circle_move(event){

    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;

    document.getElementById("txt").setAttribute("value", "X: "+x+" and Y: "+y);

    document.getElementById("canv").addEventListener("onmousemove", function(){
        context.beginPath();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.arc(x, y, 75, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
    });
}
```

**2.**

```
document.getElementById("canv").addEventListener("mousedown", 
    function(event){
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;

        document.getElementById("txt").setAttribute("value", "X: "+x+" and Y: "+y);

        context.beginPath();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.arc(x, y, 75, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
    }
);
```

**3.**

```
<canvas draggable="true" id="canv" name="canv" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onmousedown="launch"></canvas>

function loop(event){
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;

    document.getElementById("txt").setAttribute("value", "X: "+x+" and Y: "+y);

    context.beginPath();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.arc(x, y, 75, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
}

function launch(event){
    loop();
    if(event.which !== 1 || event.which !== 2 || event.which !== 3){
        launch(event);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You say you've tried various methods, yet haven't shown them

Comment: Use onmousemove event and add an additional if statement to check whether left mouse button is pressed down

Comment: @JosephYoung I updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski I think I already tried that ..

Comment: Check out my answer and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the comments and code what is happening. Basically you need a global mouse key state variable that lets the function know if there mouse key is depressed. I used the mousemove event to actually kick off the drawing of the circle. Finally, you need the distance between the cursor and center of circle to be less than the radius, otherwise you can drag the circle from outside the circle (which I presume is not what you wanted).

```js
//keep track of previous x and y coordinates
var x0 = 200;
var y0 = 300;
//keep track of mouse key state
var down = false;

var x;
var y;

//draw the initial circle someplace random
var context = document.getElementById("canv").getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
context.arc(200,300, 75, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function()
  {
    //if mousedown event is logged and we are within the area of the circle then state of down is true
    if(getDistance(x, x0, y, y0) < 75) down = true;
  });

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function()
  {
    //if mouseup event is logged then down is now false
    down = false;
  });

document.getElementById("canv").addEventListener("mousemove", 
    function(event){
      x = event.clientX;
      y = event.clientY;
     //we need to be in "down" state in order for a redraw to be necessary
     if(down)
     {  
        //set the previous coordinates to the new coordinates we are drawing.
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y;
        
        //draw the darn thing
        context.beginPath();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
        context.arc(x, y, 75, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
     }
    }
);

function getDistance(x0, x1, y0, y1)
{
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x0,2) + Math.pow(y1-y0, 2));  
  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" name="canv" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onclick="">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

PS:  I excluded the event listener from DOMContentLoaded because I painted my own circle at the beginning of the script, and it's also working. I did something wrong with that?

Comment: No your approach is actually better so I refactored my answer...I just didn't want to reference a part of the DOM that hadn't been loaded so I stuck it in that function to be safe, which turned out to be unnecessary. The added benefit now is that we only need one global context variable and don't have to reinstantiate it everytime the mousmove event gets called.

Answer (score 3):

### Animation and UI

When you drag anything on the canvas you are effectively animating the canvas. To get the best results you need to stop thinking in terms of how you did stuff with the DOM and start to codelike you are writing a game.

#### One function to rule them all.

To coordinate all that is going on you need one function that handles all the animation. Sometimes called the mainLoop in gaming circles it makes working with animated content a lot easier.

The main loop

```
function mainLoop(time){  // this is called 60 times a second if there is no delay
    // clear the canvas ready to be rendered on.
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    updateDisplay(); // call  the function that is rendering the display

    // get the next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

From the main loop you can check the current app state and call the  the appropriate functionality. In this example there is not much to its just calling `updateDisplay()`

#### KISS IO events.

The mouse, keyboard, touch, etc event handlers should not be doing any functional logic. Theses event can fire very rapidly, but the display will ony update once every 60th of a second. The is no point rendering from an event that can fire 500 times in a second when the user can only see just over 10% of the effort the CPU is doing.

The best way to write IO events is just as data loggers. Get what info you can as quick as possible and get out, don't write a different event listener for each type of event, keep the code simple, write just one event handler to handle as much as you can. If you need the keyboard add that to the same listener.

```
var mouse = (function(){
    var bounds;
    var m = {x:0,y:0,button:false};
    function mouseEvent(event){
        bounds = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        m.x = event.pageX - bounds.left + scrollX;
        m.y = event.pageY - bounds.top + scrollY;
        if(event.type === "mousedown"){
            m.button = true;
        }else if(event.type === "mouseup"){
            m.button = false;
        }
    }
    m.start = function(element){
        ["mousemove","mousedown","mouseup"].forEach(eventType => element.addEventListener(eventType, mouseEvent)); 
    }
    return m;
}())
mouse.start(canvas);
```

Now you have access to the mouse whenever you need it via the simple mouse interface.

#### Circles

There is no point adding a nice interface if there is nothing to move about in it. The following is a object that helps manage circle. It creates, draws, and locates circles.

Included is the `findClosest` function it get the circle under the mouse. It will return the smallest circle under the mouse. If nothing under the mouse it will return undefined.

```
var circles = {
    items [],
    drawCircle(){  // function for the circle
        ctx.beginPath();    
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    each(callback){  // iterator
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
            callBack(this.items[i],i);
        }
    },
    drawCircles(){
        this.each(c => {
            c.draw();
        })
    },
    addCircle(x,y,radius){
        var circle = {x, y, radius, draw : this.drawCircle};
        this.items.push(circle);
        return circle;
    },
    getClosest(pos){
        var minDist, i, dist, x, y, foundCircle;
        minDist = Infinity;
        this.each(c =>{
            x = pos.x - c.x;
            y = pos.y - c.y;
            dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            if(dist <= c.radius && dist < minDist){
                minDist = dist;
                foundCircle = c;
            }
        })
        return foundCircle;
    }
}
```

#### How to Drag.

There is a lot involved in dragging objects. You need a function to find the closest object to the mouse. You need to provide feed back so that the user can see what can be dragged.

You may end up with many different drag type events. Drag to create, drag to move, drag something onto the canvas, or manipulate a custom rendered UI object. If you manage the dragging state from one object you can ensure that you dont accidentally click a UI item when dragging a circle.

When dragging starts you check what the drag will be doing. Then you flag that you are dragging, and indicate what the drag is to do. (see updateDisplay function)

While the drag is active do that action. When the mouse is up then just deactivate the drag

```
var dragging = {
    started : false, // true if dragging
    type : null,     // string with the type of drag event
    currentObj : null,  // what we are dragging
    startX : 0,      // info about where the drag started
    startY : 0,
    start(type, obj){  // called at the start of a drag.
        this.startX = mouse.x;
        this.startY = mouse.y;
        this.started = true;
        this.type = type;
        this.currentObj = obj;
    }
}
```

Then the render function. It is called once every frame. I checks if the mouse button is down, what to do if it is, sets the cursor so people know what to do, and draws the circles.

```
var cursor = "default";  // to hold the cursor
var overCircle = null;   // this holds whatever circle happens to be under the mouse when not dragging
function updateDisplay(){
    var x,y, c;
    cursor = "default";  // set default cursor
    // check that the mouse if over the canvas
    if(mouse.x >= 0 && mouse.x < canvas.width && mouse.y >= 0 && mouse.y < canvas.height){
        cursor = "crosshair";
    }
    // is the mouse button down
    if(mouse.button){  // the button is down
        if(!dragging.started){  // if not dragging start 
            if(overCircle){  // start a move drag if over a circle
                dragging.start("move",overCircle)
                overCircle = null;
            }else{ // start a create drag 
                dragging.start("create",circles.addCircle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1));
            }
        }
        c = dragging.currentObj;
        // Update the drag state o fthe object being draged and the type of drag
        if(dragging.type === "create"){
            x = c.x - mouse.x;
            y = c.y - mouse.y;
            c.radius = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }else if(dragging.type === "move"){
            x = dragging.startX - mouse.x;
            y = dragging.startY - mouse.y;
            c.x -= x;
            c.y -= y;
            dragging.startX = mouse.x;
            dragging.startY = mouse.y;
        }
        cursor = "none";
    } else {  // button must be up
        if(dragging.started){ // have we been dragging something.
            dragging.started = false; // drop it
        }
    }
    // draw the circles
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    circles.draw();
    // if not dragging 
    if(!dragging.started){
        // find circle under the mouse
        c = circles.getClosest(mouse);
        if(c !== undefined){  // if there is a circle under the mouse highlight it
            cursor = "move";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,255,255,0.1)";
            c.draw();
            ctx.fill();
            overCircle = c;
        }else{
            overCircle = null;
        }
    }
    // set the cursor.
    canvas.style.cursor = cursor;
}
```

#### As a working example.

```js
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.border = "1px black solid";
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 200;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    function mainLoop(time){  // this is called 60 times a second if there is no delay
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);        
        updateDisplay(); // call  the function that is rendering the display
        // get the next frame
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
    // request the first frame. It will not start untill all the code below has been run
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

    
    var mouse = (function(){
        var bounds;
        var m = {x:0,y:0,button:false};
        function mouseEvent(event){
            bounds = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
            m.x = event.pageX - bounds.left + scrollX;
            m.y = event.pageY - bounds.top + scrollY;
            if(event.type === "mousedown"){
                m.button = true;
            }else if(event.type === "mouseup"){
                m.button = false;
            }
        }
        m.start = function(element){
            ["mousemove","mousedown","mouseup"].forEach(eventType => element.addEventListener(eventType, mouseEvent)); 
        }
        return m;
    }())
    mouse.start(canvas);


    var circles = {
        items : [],
        drawCircle(){  // function for the circle
            ctx.beginPath();    
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.stroke();
        },
        each(callback){  // iterator
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
                callback(this.items[i],i);
            }
        },
        draw(){
            this.each(c => {
                c.draw();
            })
        },
        addCircle(x,y,radius){
            var circle = {x, y, radius, draw : this.drawCircle};
            this.items.push(circle);
            return circle;
        },
        getClosest(pos){
            var minDist, i, dist, x, y, foundCircle;
            minDist = Infinity;
            this.each(c =>{
                x = pos.x - c.x;
                y = pos.y - c.y;
                dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                if(dist <= c.radius){
                    if(foundCircle === undefined || (foundCircle && c.radius < foundCircle.radius)){
                        minDist = dist;
                        foundCircle = c;
                    }
                }
            })
            return foundCircle;
        }
    }
    var dragging = {
        started : false,
        type : null,
        currentObj : null,  // what we are dragging
        startX : 0,
        startY : 0,
        start(type, obj){
            this.startX = mouse.x;
            this.startY = mouse.y;
            this.started = true;
            this.type = type;
            this.currentObj = obj;
        }
        
    }
    var cursor = "default";
    var overCircle = null;
    function updateDisplay(){
        var x,y, c;
        cursor = "default"
        if(mouse.x >= 0 && mouse.x < canvas.width && mouse.y >= 0 && mouse.y < canvas.height){
            cursor = "crosshair";
        }
        if(mouse.button){  // the button is down
            if(!dragging.started){
                if(overCircle){
                    dragging.start("move",overCircle)
                    overCircle = null;

                }else{
                    dragging.start("create",circles.addCircle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1));
                }
            }
            c = dragging.currentObj;
            if(dragging.type === "create"){
                x = c.x - mouse.x;
                y = c.y - mouse.y;
                c.radius = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }else if(dragging.type === "move"){
                x = dragging.startX - mouse.x;
                y = dragging.startY - mouse.y;
                c.x -= x;
                c.y -= y;
                dragging.startX = mouse.x;
                dragging.startY = mouse.y;
            }
            cursor = "none";
        } else {  // button must be up
            if(dragging.started){ // have we been dragging something.
                dragging.started = false; // drop it
            }
        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        circles.draw();
        
        if(!dragging.started){
            c = circles.getClosest(mouse);
            if(c !== undefined){
                cursor = "move";
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,255,255,0.1)";
                c.draw();
                ctx.fill();
                overCircle = c;
            }else{
                overCircle = null;
            }
        }
        canvas.style.cursor = cursor;
    }
```

```html
<div style="font-family:12px arial;">Click drag to create circle</div>
```

> Note this is written in ES6 and will not run on IE without some type of compiler.

Comment: Very detailed answer, however I am still a noob, and I was looking for the easiest answer. Thank you very much for your work!

Comment: @default It all depends on what the end result is going to be. If it's a more complicated game then you probably want a more robust rendering cycle like the one painted above. But if its a silly little animation then it might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
var offsetx,offsety,posx,posy,run;
  window.onmousedown=function(e){
 run=true;
 offsetx=e.clientX;
 offsety=e.clientY;

 };
 window.onmouseup=function(){
 run=false;
 };
window.onmousemove=function(e){
if(run){
 movedx=e.clientX-offsetx;//mouse moved this value
 movedy=e.clientY-offsety;
 posx+=movedx;
 posy+=movedyy;
 offsetx=e.clientX;
 offsety=e.clientY
 //todo draw at posx,posy
 }
 };
 //todo draw circle+set posx,posy to its position
```